# How to handle questions that ask for technology the asker doesn't know about?

Tags: discussion

I just ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37466080/generic-table-to-display-property-data-for-various-objects) and I don't know if it should be closed or not.

It seems Off-Topic, as requiring for a Tutorial, but actually the user doesn't know the name that is behind what he wants (e.g. DataBinding if I understood the question correctly).

It looks Too Broad, but it's not really, answer might get long, but I think there is only one question, and there won't be too many answers to this problem.

I believe there is some effort put in that question, as it is describing the problem. It seems to me that this user doesn't know what is DataBinding and is looking for a way to achieve just that.

So I don't know, I left a comment pointing at DataBinding to check if that's the user wants. But I didn't know if I should flag it or not, nor what to do with that.

Maybe I understood it wrong and it should be closed or answered right away and I should just go back to my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that this person is asking is likely because they *don't* fully understand the exact technology they need.  Just because they don't know doesn't mean it's eligible to be closed.

You say so as much yourself:  it looks like some effort has been put into the question.  I defer more to you on this since I don't have knowledge of VB, but if I were to translate it into a language I did understand, I'd at least be satisfied with what they're describing as something that can be answered objectively.

I *might* prod the person for a bit more information in terms of, "What happened when you tried the unified approach?  Are there any differences of implementation between the individual approaches?", but I probably wouldn't immediately strike to close it.

My advice:  If you think you understand what they mean but you're not sure, leave a comment to ask them some clarifying questions about what they're after or what they've had trouble with.  Once you understand what's going on, then and only then would I recommend making a decision.

Comment: thank you I will do that and wait for OP to respond to my comments

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't seem to be off topic for the reason you mentioned actually:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

If you read the entire thing, it would indicate that an **on-topic** question might:

- describe the problem
- describe what has been done so far to solve it

It is vague, but probably not too broad. It seems to be answered in some capacity in the first comment, actually.